# Bing Maps REST can't draw polygon with console app

Tags: rest, console-application, bing-maps, polygon

As a console app, I'm creating maps with Bing Maps, with lat/lon and pushpins. Saving as a jpg. Everything is working great. NOW, however, I'd like to draw a polygon layered on said map[s]. It seems this might not be possible; I cannot find the answer. Dynamic via web page it seems is the only way; I need it to happen with a console app.

Answer (score 0):

The custom polygon as well as custom polyline are not supported features on the REST service.

Since you're in a console application and as you're saving the image as JPG file, you can draw your own content onto the image using GDI or other technology to manipulate the image directly. Currently, there is no other way.

Comment: Thanks. That's about what I gleaned from hours of searching. I have come across an interesting method for translating lat/lon to y/x (pixels) if anyone's interested.

Comment: Glad that this solution was one that worked for you.
In order to help people, here are the link to the MSDN with all the methods to convert location to pixel and other operations in a geographical context: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx